# gradle:how to run task in a method

Tags: gradle

i want run a task in a method or function,how to write code,can you give me a demo?
thanks.

for example ...

this is a task.

```
task releaseJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
    into('build/output/jar')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('calsses.jar', 'core' + '0.0.1' + '.jar')
}
```

i want run it in

```
artifacts {
   ...same as  call releaseJar
    def myreleasejar = file 'build/output/jar/core0.0.1.jar'
    archives myreleasejar
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never explicitly call tasks. Gradle will determine what tasks are needed to run based on a dependency graph. Therefore, you should instead declare task dependencies and Gradle will take care of the rest. In this case, you can tell Gradle what tasks are responsible for building an artifact.

```
artifacts {
    archives(file("${buildDir}/output/jar/core0.0.1.jar")) {
        builtBy releaseJar
    }
}
```

Comment: A problem occurred evaluating project ':core'
> Could not find method file() for arguments[............here is full path]

Comment: I updated my answer. Try the updated syntax. It might be trying to pass the configuration closure to the `file()` method. If you still get an error, please link to the full stacktrace.

Comment: i'm define a method  to copy and rename file,instead of task.
thank you`(*∩_∩*)′